# Are Protected Auto-Cast Methods Ok?

Tags: java, programming-practices

I often have superclasses that contain a more abstracted form of a class as a member variable than my subclasses need. I find my code littered `((ClassName)variableName).methodName()`. Is the best way to solve this to create a protected/private method called something like `getVariableNameAsClass()`? It's not much shorter in letters, but an IDE can do that much faster than maneuvering around with the keys to add in parenthesis. Or is there a better solution?

The reason I need to cast is because all of the subclasses of `Line` use an `Output` class, so I put the getters and setters that relate to the `Output` class in the base class. The issue is that an `AudioLine` uses and `AudioOutput`, and needs to define additional methods that use the more specific features.

**So, here's my entire class design:** I have a `Line` class with two subclasses, `VideoLine` and `AudioLine`, which delegate some of their functionality to a internal `Output` class. `Output` class has a `AudioOutput` and `VideoOutput` subclass. I defined all the functionality for the `Line` class that relies only on methods from the `Output` class inside the `Line` class, in accordance with DRY. `Line`'s `AudioLine` and `VideoLine` both deligate additional functionality to `AudioOutput` and `VideoOutput`. Since they both set up the `Output` protected variable in their constructors (and therefor KNOW what subclass it contains), it seemed to make sense to caste it.

Comment: I don't understand.  What's keeping you from just storing the more concrete form in the superclass?

Comment: If you could give some details about the abstract class and what it's missing that you need to constantly cast it to other types for, we could maybe give you better guidance on solving your model design issue. Auto-casting methods like you refer to are really not a best approach most times, occasionally they're acceptable when using generics.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt Because the more concrete form is not used in all the subclasses.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I added more information.

Comment: Show a class diagram. You have a design flaw.

Comment: @user61852 I added a complete explanation of my class design (or at least the relevant parts)

Comment: If `Line` and `VideoLine` are not interchangeable, then you have a design flaw.

Comment: @user61852 They are interchangeable. As in, VideoLine can be used for a Line, but, like most hierarchys, the VideoLine offers more specialized features just for Video

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a protected `Output` field on `Line` implies that any implementation of `Output` can be used with any implementation of `Line`. In your case this is not true, and the repeated casts are a good indicator that your class structure isn't as type-safe as it should be.

(Imagine if, due to a change or a bug, `Line` were to replace the `VideoOutput` required by `VideoLine` with an `AudioOutput` - you wouldn't know until it crashed)

Recommendation:

Move the output field to the sub-classes. Two options (I prefer the former, but consider both valid):

1) Make the `Output`-dependent methods abstract and provide utility methods to do the work

```
public abstract class Line{
    public abstract void doThing();
    protected final void doThing(Output output){
        ...
    }
}
public class VideoLine extends Line{
    private VideoOutput output;
    public void doThing(){
        super.doThing(output);
    }
}
```

2) Provide a `getOutput()` method for the super-class to use.

```
public abstract class Line{
    public abstract Output getOutput();
    public void doThing(){
        Output output = getOutput();
        ...
    }
}
public class VideoLine extends Line{
    private VideoOutput output;
    protected Output getOutput(){
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: But is there a reason why this is better than casting it?

Comment: Type safety. I've updated my answer.